# Is there a way to copy live path effects from one object to another in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape, path-effects

Inkscape has a feature called "Live Path Effects" (PATH > PATH EFFECTS). This allows you to apply a style to a path and have said style update live a you update the path.

It's nice, but has one limitation for me in that you have to apply it individually to each object one-by-one. This can be tedious.

Is there a way to copy a path effect and it's settings from one element to another?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As of Inkscape 0.91, yes you can copy and paste path effects.

1. Apply whatever path effects you want to one path.
2. Copy that path <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.
3. Select the path(s) to which you want to apply the copied path's effects.
4. Click `Path > Paste Path Effect` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

This will preserve any settings you have on the path effects as well.

Comment: Thanks! This works. Mostly. Well, good enough. One weird anomaly (probably a bug) while you can apply a path effect to a object, you can't paste said effect onto another object. You can only paste it on to paths. So if you have a square object, you first have to OBJECT TO PATH to paste the effect.