# Edit Multiple Freehand Stroke Widths at Once in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape, path, stroke, brush

I'm trying to ink a drawing using the freehand stroke tool in Inkscape. I understand that this tool creates filled shapes rather than lines with strokes, so I'm using the Path Effects Editor to change the width. However, when I make a new stroke, the width resets to the default value of 1. I would like all of my line widths to be the same, but when I select all of the lines, I'm told that I can only edit one stroke at a time. Is there a way for me to change the stroke width for all of my lines at once?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer using this: [Is there a way to copy live path effects from one object to another in Inkscape?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/60933/is-there-a-way-to-copy-live-path-effects-from-one-object-to-another-in-inkscape), but first using Remove Path Effects so that two of the same effects are not pasted on top of each other.