# How set a common property of a selection of several objects?

Tags: inkscape

How do I, for instance, set the width of all selected objects to the same value in one go?

When I select several objects and then set the width, I of course change the width of the entire selection. How do I go about setting the individual widths of all selected objects in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the width of one object, and then copy that object (<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>).

Select all other objects, then execute *Edit -> Paste Size -> Paste Width Separately*.

This works for object size only. For other properties you may use other tools such as fill & stroke, transform, arrange,

Comment: You can do something similar with [path effects](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/60942/16458) as well.

Comment: I often use paste style but had completely forgotten about paste width! Thanks.

Comment: This isn't working for me. :(